# Extract sub image BitmapImage

Tags: c#, image, extract, bitmapimage, win-universal-app

I'm working on a C# Universal Project(Windows Desktop+Windows Phone) that requires me to display a lot of images. I'm trying to make use of the 'compressed' image I have been given.

This is the image: http://gyazo.com/b592a5fb6b4754c0aecc0223be56a3cf

The image consists out of sub-images that are all put into 1 image to save space. In the past I have programmed C# Desktop apps and used the following code to extract an image from the image that contains the sub images.

```
public Bitmap Load(int x, int y, int w, int h, string sprite)
{
    Bitmap original = new Bitmap(@"Images\" + sprite);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    return (Bitmap)original.Clone(rectangle, original.PixelFormat);
}
```

Now that I am working on a Universal application (Desktop+Phone) the above code is no longer valid. I am forced to work with BitmapImages instead of Bitmap.

I have tried to convert it:

```
public BitmapImage Load(double x, double y, double w, double h, string sprite)
{
    BitmapImage original = new BitmapImage();
    original.UriSource = new Uri(@"Images\" + sprite);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.Width = w;
    rectangle.Height = h;
    rectangle.RadiusX = x;
    rectangle.RadiusY = y;
    return (BitmapImage)original.clone(rectangle, original.PixelFormat);
}
```

But the .clone and .PixelFormat functions are not present with BitmapImages.
Any help in converting this code to work in C# Universal App would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're written `.clone` instead of `.Clone` in the latter example. You might want to look into the `BitmapImage.CopyPixels` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can't extract the pixels from a BitmapImage. You'll need to either use a WriteableBitmap or [BitmapDecoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.aspx) to get access to the actual pixels.

With a BitmapDecoder you can read in specific segments of the image by calling [GetPixelDataAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br226193.aspx) with a [BitmapTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.aspx) with just the Bounds you want to crop out of the bitmap.

With either a WriteableBitmap or a BitmapEncoder you can read in the full bitmap and then extract the sub-images after the fact. There isn't anything built in to copy sub-images out, but the math to find and copy a rectangle isn't hard and there are third party extensions (such as [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)'s Crop extension method) which can do it for you.